# R Plyr Rename multiple columns in list of dataframes

Tags: r, plyr

Only just discovered `Plyr` and it has saved me a tonne of lines combining multiple data frames which is great.  BUT I have another renaming problem I cannot fathom.

I have a list, which contains a number of data frames (this is a subset as there are actually 108 in the real list).

```
> str(mydata)
List of 4
 $ C11:'data.frame':    8 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "n >= 1","n >= 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE: num [1:8] 1 1 1 1 0.96 0.91 0.74 0.5
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL  : num [1:8] 0.88 0.88 0.88 0.88 0.9 0.91 0.94 0.95
 $ C12:'data.frame':    8 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "n >= 1","n >= 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE: num [1:8] 1 1 1 1 0.96 0.89 0.86 0.72
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL  : num [1:8] 0.91 0.91 0.91 0.91 0.93 0.96 0.97 0.98
 $ C13:'data.frame':    8 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "n >= 1","n >= 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE: num [1:8] 1 1 1 1 0.94 0.79 0.65 0.46
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL  : num [1:8] 0.85 0.85 0.85 0.85 0.88 0.9 0.92 0.91
 $ C14:'data.frame':    8 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "n >= 1","n >= 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE: num [1:8] 1 1 1 1 0.98 0.95 0.88 0.74
  ..$ n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL  : num [1:8] 0.91 0.91 0.91 0.91 0.92 0.94 0.95 0.98
```

What I really want to achieve is for each data frame to have the columns prepended with the title of the dataframe.  So in the example the columns would be:

`C11.X`, `C11.n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE` & `C11.n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL`

`C12.X`, `C12.n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE` & `C12.n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL`

`C13.X`, `C13.n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE` & `C13.n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL`

`C14.X`, `C14.n.ENSEMBLE.COVERAGE` & `C14.n.ENSEMBLE.RECALL`

Can anyone suggest an elegant approach to renaming columns like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example using the iris data set:

```
# produce a named list of data.frames as sample data:
dflist <- split(iris, iris$Species)
# store the list element names:
n <- names(dflist)
# rename the elements:
Map(function(df, vec) setNames(df, paste(vec, names(df), sep = ".")), dflist, n)
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Only thing is that final 'Map' doesn't seem to change the names in dflist BUT it does output the correct dflist to the console.

Comment: @BarneyC, correct. Use `dflist <- Map(...)` to permanently change the data.

Comment: Duh!   Been a very long day.  Thanks awfully.  Works perfectly.

Comment: As an extension to this... how would you NOT apply the df name to the first column?  So  X stays as X.

Comment: @BarneyC, an option would be: `Map(function(df, vec) setNames(df, c(names(df)[1], paste(vec, names(df)[-1], sep = "."))), dflist, n)`

Comment: Outstanding.  Not sure I understand the Map(function in the original answer, but I do get how you did the naming in the second case.  Cheers for that - a HUGE help.

Comment: @BarneyC, Welcome and glad it helped. Perhaps it helps you to study the help file for `?Map` (and remember that `Map` is the same as `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` )